# Can jQuery selectors be applied to an element rather than the whole document?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
jQuery('td[class=bgoff]').each(function() {
    var td = jQuery(this);
    ... no apply selector to "this" only
});
```

I'm working with tabular data in html and trying to parse the contents of each TD (they are not uniquely identifiable).

Using XPath, I can prepend the path of "this" to additional selecting.

How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With jQuery you have the option of supplying a second parameter after the selector expression and that becomes a context that jQuery uses to limit scope of the lookup. Learn more [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext)

Answer (score 15):

You can also use .find(expression) if you already have a jquery object within which you wish to search.

In your example:

```
jQuery('td[class=bgoff]').each(function() {
    var td = jQuery(this);
    $(td).find( <selector to search within td> );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [jQuery source](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/core.js#L73):

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, context)  
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
```