# how do i set limit of selection in jquery asmselect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery asmselect. I want to set a limit of selection. I don't know how to do it. Plz someone help me for my problem.
my html code

my page runs ok, but i want to give the limit 4 that one user can select. please help me............

```
enter code here

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.asmselect.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.asmselect.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                         $("select[multiple]").asmSelect({
                       addItemTarget: 'bottom',
                       animate: true,
                           highlight: true,
                           sortable: true
                           });
                      }); 
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
           <form action="">
               <select multiple="multiple" name="city" id="citty">
            <option value=""  selected="selected">-Select City-</option>
        <option value="1">Anugul</option>
        <option value="2">Asika</option>
        <option value="3">Balangir</option>
        <option value="4">Balasore</option>
        <option value="5">Barbil</option>
        <option value="6">Bargarh</option>
        <option value="7">Baripada</option>
        <option value="8">Basudebpur</option>
        <option value="9">Belpahar</option>
        </select>
           </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How about this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624757/can-jquery-selectors-be-applied-to-an-element-rather-than-the-whole-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUMBt/)

```
            $("select[multiple]").change(function(){
                var noOfItemsSelected = $("select[multiple] option:selected").length;
                if(noOfItemsSelected === 4){
                    $("select[class=asmSelect]").prop('disabled', true);
                }else{
                    $("select[class=asmSelect]").prop('disabled', false);
                }        
            });
```